Is there a CLI substitution for the smbtree command available?
I have come to realize that smbtree only works when setting the Samba parameters in the smb.conf file:
client min protocol = NT1
client min protocol = NT1

This is not good, of course. Is there a substitution or alternative CLI available that supports SMB2 and higher to the command that would produce similar output (to include the domain, server, and share properties)?
root@xubuntu:# smbtree
Password for [DHOME\root]:
DHOME
    \\LAPTOP1               LAPTOP1
    \\LAPTOP2               LAPTOP2
    \\XUBUNTU               XUBUNTU


Could you please provide more context? For example, the version of Xubuntu you are using. If it is a desktop or a server, or a cloud instance, Are you trying to access it from within your home network or across the Internet.

Please edit your question.

Running on Xubuntu 24.04.1 Desktop, Vitualbox host is Windows 11 Home, no cloud. On my home network with a mix of Windows 10 and Windows 7 laptops.

Please exit your question.

I just found an alternative to smbtree which doesn't require the use of NT1 in the smb.conf file. Using nbtscan provides output very consistent to what I'm looking for to analyze the computer names on my home network. It doesn't display the shares, but that's ok. Using smbclient does that part. This answers my question.
$ nbtscan 10.0.0.2-254
Doing NBT name scan for addresses from 10.0.0.2-254

IP address       NetBIOS Name     Server    User             MAC address
----------------------------------------------------------------------

